# Effective spring constant of elastic band

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, spring

How do you derive the effective spring constant of an elastic band stretched in different 2D shapes that being triangle with 3 anchor points or hexagonal with 6 anchor points? In a previous question one answer comes up with the formula

$$
K_{eff}=2K\cos^2\theta,
$$

I am confused on how they derived this.
[Rubber Band Forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29318/)

Comment: If you have three or more "anchor points", where are you pulling that requires a spring constant?

Comment: The model is a group of 19 atoms (cylinders) in a hexagon shape, a smaller atom in a space between three large atoms with an elastic band surrounding, My thinking is that the 6 corner atoms would be the "pegs" mentioned in the other question  and angle would be 120 degrees. We need the spring constant in order to calculate the change in tension or the force required for the interstitial atom to squeeze through to the next available space.

Comment: Try applying $K_\mathrm{eff}=(1/l)(dU/dl)$, where $U$ is the strain energy for the entire system and $l$ is the deformation distance. (For a simple spring with spring constant $k$ pulled axially, where $U=kl^2/2$, we have simply $K_\mathrm{eff}=(1/l)[d(kl^2/2)/dl]=k$. Things become more interesting when multiple springs are connected in a spatial assembly.)

Comment: I was advised to look at the derivation for excess pressure of a liquid drop and reduce it down to two dimensions, can anyone help with this?